# Windows forms turn off waitCursor on the form

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

```
$size = 200
$Form = [Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
$Form.ControlBox = $true
$Form.Width = $Size
$Form.Height= $Size
$Form.Topmost = $True
$Form.UseWaitCursor= $false
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Cursor=[Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Cross

$Form.Show()
```

I have a problem with wait cursor on form. How to turn off wait cursor on the form?

*If i use ShowDialog(), there is no problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a PS code issue. It's a UX/UI design choice. You must choose the right design option for your UX/UI regardless of the code behind language or editor in use.

Show() vs. ShowDialog() in .NET

The form class' ShowDialog method functions differently than its Show method. Here's how:

- ShowDialog's returned value can be used to determine how the user
  closed the form (using the DialogResult property).
- ShowDialog does not call the Dispose method automatically on its
  close. However, Show, when modeless, does dispose upon close.

One of the benefits of the modal dialog not being disposed after it's closed is that the data can be retrieved from the modal form.

A good practice is to call the Dispose method in a final block, when using the ShowDialog method, which releases resources and handles from memory.

ShowDialog the form is shown in a modal window. A modal form generally is used to show a dialog that must be closed until it takes back to the caller.

The Show method will return after the form is displayed and the next code to execute depends on the users action on the New, or any other currently open form that the user may choose.

Disposal
When a non modal form is closed, the Dispose will automatically be called by WinForms. This can be seen by setting a break point in the Dispose method (C#) and then closing the form. Because of this, there is no need to call Dispose from the code that created this form.

Modal
Modal, or dialog style forms prevent the user from removing the focus from the form. The user must either open another form, or close the form. Forms opened before the modal form cannot be accessed by the user.

On the other hand, the show method just shows the form and continues executing the next line of the caller.

The ShowDialog method functions differently than the Show method. ShowDialog blocks execution until the form has been closed. Because of this, the Dispose can follow the ShowDialog call immediately as it will not be called until the form has been closed. If the Dispose call was made immediately after a Show method, the form would simply flash on the screen as it would be shown, and then immediately be disposed of after it was shown.

Disposal
WinForms does not automatically call the Dispose method when a user closes a modal form. Because of this, the Dispose is explicitly called. In Visual Basic this is done by calling the Dispose method directly, while in C# the using construct is used.

Returning a Result
The ShowDialog method also differs from the Show method in that it offers a return value. The result can be used to determine how the user closed the form. To do this, the event code can either set the return value, or more simply the DialogResult property of buttons can be used.

To see this in action, drop two buttons on a modal form. Now set the DialogResult property of one to OK, and the other to Cancel. This will cause the buttons to close the form, and return the specified value as the return value of ShowDialog.

Lastly, With PowerShell, it's also been noted that:

> One should avoid using Show() from PowerShell as it requires a message pump and that isn't something the PowerShell console provides on the thread that creates your form. ShowDialog() works because the OS does the message pumping during this modal call.

So, if you don't want to use ShowDialog(), and you don't want that hang you get from Show(), then your option is to use...

```
$size = 200
$Form = [Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
$Form.ControlBox = $true
$Form.Width = $Size
$Form.Height= $Size
$Form.Topmost = $True
$Form.UseWaitCursor= $false
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Cursor=[Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Cross

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form)
```

See more details here:
[Application.Run Method (System.Windows.Forms) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run)